# Support multiple Sub-Domains in CloudFront

Tags: subdomain, amazon-cloudfront

I have a CloudFront setup on AWS.
I want to support multiple sub-domains under it. 
ex. test1.mydomain.com and hello.mydomain.com and so on.
But I don't want to use wildcard as it will start supporting anything in subdomain.

Is there a solution for this? Also, if yes, Can I apply that solution programatically, as and when I need to support a given domain?

Thanks

Comment: CNAME limit per distribution is 100 and can be increased, there is no api to specifically add cname, everytime you want to add a new cname, you need to make update distribution api call with new cname added which will give you new etag.

Comment: Thanks James, Can I handle this using a AWS Lamda Edge function? I that the recommended way?